# How to use chrono::microseconds with Pybind11?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++-chrono, pybind11

The error boils down to this snippet.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <pybind11/chrono.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace chr = std::chrono;
namespace py = pybind11;

struct Time {
    chr::microseconds elapsed;

    Time(const chr::microseconds& elapsed) : elapsed(elapsed) {}
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(CppModule, m) {
    py::class_<Time>(m, "Time")
        .def(py::init<const chr::microseconds&>())
        .def("elapsed", &Time::elapsed);
}
```

When I try to build it, I get the following error.

```
'pybind11::cpp_function::cpp_function': no overloaded function takes 4 arguments
```

What should I do to read `Time::elapsed` on the Python side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `def` binds functions. Methods `def_readwrite` and `def_readonly` bind fields.

`Time::elapsed` is a field. That's why `def` cannot be used.

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(CppModule, m) {
    py::class_<Time>(m, "Time")
        .def(py::init<const chr::microseconds&>())
        .def_readwrite("elapsed", &Time::elapsed);
}
```

Note that on Python side type `chr::microseconds` is converted to `datetime.timedelta`. To get the total number of microseconds divide it by 1 microsecond.

```py
import CppModule as m
import datetime

t = m.Time(datetime.timedelta(minutes=10, seconds=5))
print(t.elapsed)
print(t.elapsed // datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1))
```

Output.

```
0:10:05
605000000
```